# char* or LPCWSTR in windows functions

Tags: c++, windows, char, directx

I followed a tutorial on creating a Windows - Window with the standard windows.h header.

```
WNDCLASSEX wc;
...
ec.lpszClassName = applicationName;
```

At first when compiling this, applicationName was a char* and everything was fine but now I needed to recreate the project (MSVC++ by the way) and as I was trying to compile it, it needed to be a LPCWSTR. I stumbled upon this quite a lot and would like to know, why it sometimes accepts char* and sometimes not!? Am I missing somthing in my project settings?

By the way:
the same thing happens with

```
D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(d3ddevice, filename, NULL, NULL, &m_texture, NULL);
```

where filename once accepted char* but not anymore...

Comment: Doesn't the `W` in `LPCWSTR` mean `wchar_t`?

Comment: afaik, yes. but why sometimes char and sometimes wchar???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the project settings under "Configuration Properties->General" there is an option called "Character Set".  Setting this to "Use Unicode Character Set" will cause many Windows API functions to accept a `wchar_t*` instead of `char*`. If it is set to "Use Multibyte Character Set" the API functions will take `char*` instead of `wchar_t*`.

Answer (score 3):

MSVC projects have a "Unicode" property you can toggle on or off. When it is off, all Win32 functions use `char` as the fundamental character type (so a function expecting you to pass a string will require a `const char*).

When it is enabled, `wchar_t` is the character type used. (So functions use `const wchar_t*` for string parameters).

The API actually defines two structs, `WNDCLASSEXA` and `WNDCLASSEXW`. The former uses `char`, and the latter uses `wchar_t`.

Depending on whether Unicode is enabled (which defines a `_UNICODE` preprocessor macro), one of these is aliased to the name `WNDCLASSEX`.

So when Unicode is enabled, `WNDCLASSEX` actually means `WNDCLASSEXW`.

The same is true for all other functions and types in the API which deal with character data. They all have `_A` and `_W` variants

If you want to not depend on the project property setting, you can be explicit about which variant you want to use:

Instead of creating a `WNDCLASSEX` (which can be two different things), create a `WNDCLASSEXW` (which *always* uses `wchar_t`). And instead of calling `RegisterClass`, call either `RegisterClassA` or `RegisterClassW`.